# 'Conflict' with action deleted_post and is_admin()

Tags: admin, hooks, redirect, actions

I created a delete button on frontend for blog posts and custom type posts and I would redirect to a specific page after deleting them, I looked around on google and I found all solutions like this:

```
add_action('deleted_post', 'my_trashed_post_handler', 10);
function my_trashed_post_handler($post_id) {
        wp_redirect( get_option('siteurl') );
        exit;
}
```

The code works well ,but I don't want change the standard behavior of the backend so I did in this way:

```
add_action('deleted_post', 'woffice_trashed_post_handler', 10);
function woffice_trashed_post_handler($post_id) {
    if(!is_admin()) {
        wp_redirect( get_option('siteurl') );
        exit;
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work because I discovered that is_admin return always true, also if I delete a post by front end.

To create the deleting link by frontend I use this function:

```
get_delete_post_link(get_the_ID();
```

How can I solve it and redirect to a specific page after I delete a post just by front end or just by a specific link/button?

**UPDATE:** Thanks to zlatev reply I am able to trigger it and avoid the is_admin issue, now I have another very odd problem:

1. I create a new post
2. I open it and I click delete by fronend
3. I am redirected to the blog listing page (my custom edirect url)
4. The post is not deleted
5. I hope the post again and I click delete again by frontend
6. I am redirected to the same page
7. The post is deleted on second time

I tested it many times and it's always deleted on second time, I create the deleting url with this and the url is always the same:

```
add_query_arg( 'origin', 'fe-blog', get_delete_post_link(get_the_ID(), '', true))
```

The code That I use for rdirect is this:

```
add_action('deleted_post', 'woffice_trashed_post_handler');
function woffice_trashed_post_handler() {
    if( isset( $_GET['origin'] ) && ($_GET['origin'] == 'fe-blog' || $_GET['origin'] == 'fe-wiki' || $_GET['origin'] == 'fe-project') ) {
        switch($_GET['origin']){
            case 'fe-blog':
                $blog_page = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
                if(empty($blog_page)){
                    $pages = get_pages(array(
                        'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
                        'meta_value' => 'page-templates/blog.php'
                    ));
                    $blog_page = $pages[0]->ID;
                }
                //var_dump(get_permalink($blog_page));
                //die();
                wp_redirect( get_permalink($blog_page) );
                break;
        }
        exit();
    }
}
```

I am using a wrong hook?

Answer (score 0):

More importantly you should notice what link is produced by `get_delete_post_link()`. It's an admin link `is_admin()` check will be always `true`. Instead you need something else that helps match the request. Try adding and query arg to your delete link.

```
add_query_arg( 'origin', 'fe', get_delete_post_link( get_the_ID() ) );
```

then in the action

```
add_action('deleted_post', 'woffice_trashed_post_handler', 10);
function woffice_trashed_post_handler($post_id) {
    if( isset( $_POST['origin'] ) && $_POST['origin'] == 'fe' ) {
        wp_redirect( get_option('siteurl') );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Zlatav, thank you, that's solution is awesome, in this way I can trigger it perfectly.

Now I have another poblem, maybe caused by a wrong use of the hook, I edit my question right now adding information :)